# Split string into array and print each element on a new line with commandline

Tags: command-line, sed, awk, split

I'm having a String which is seperated by commas like `a,b,c,d,e,f` that I want to split into an array with the comma as seperator. Then I want to print each element on a new line. The problem I'm having is that all cli tools I know so far(sed, awk, grep) only work on lines, but how do I get a string into a format that can be used by these tools. What i'v tried so far is

```
echo "a,b,c,d,e,f" | awk -F', ' '{print $i"\n"}'
```

How can I get this output

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

from this input

```
a,b,c,d,e,f
```

?

Comment: I'm not clear what you're really asking. You can translate commas to newlines with "tr": `echo a, b, c, d | tr , '\n'` -- that leaves spaces at the start of the b/c/d lines.

Comment: `IFS=',' read -a array <<<"a,b,c,d,e,f" ; printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}`

Comment: @glennjackman `tr -s ', ' '\n'`

Comment: `line="a,b,c,d,e,f" ; echo -e ${line//,/\\n}`

Comment: @Costas, hmm, what if there's a space within a field? `tr -s ', ' '\n'` will split the field into multiple lines.

Comment: @glennjackman Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sticking with your awk ... just make sure you understand the difference between a **field** and a **record** separator :}

```
echo "a,b,c,d,e,f" | awk 'BEGIN{RS=","}{$1=$1}1'
```

But the tr solution in the comments is preferable.

Comment: What's with the `$i`?

Comment: good question; purious (from OPs incantation). will delete :)

Comment: `awk '{$1=$1}1' RS=,` looks shorter with trailing `\n`ewline removed